# How to allow certain email address to authenticate GAE application?

Tags: google-app-engine

In my GAE application I want to allow `only three` (ex. abc@mydomain.com, xyx@mydomain.com and abc@gmail.com) email addresses to `authenticate`, but i could not configure it. While createing GAE application it has three option which does not match my requirement. Anyone helping on this is highly appreciated.
Thanx in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom authentication in google app engine (python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020736/custom-authentication-in-google-app-engine-python)

Comment: @Paul, In  your link the accepted answer and other answers are not really helpful for me because they have suggested to use third party library. Is there any application setting in GAE or in web.xml ?

Comment: To do what? Authenticate? If what you want is not available then logically all that is left is to write your own or use a 3rd party. There are 3 options, Google accounts, Google Apps Accounts or OpenID. Just accept the fact that you have to write your own. It's quite simple - ask the user for their email address and check it's in the allowed list, if so check their password hash against the password hash you are storing. Security is difficult and you should not implement it yourself unless you have to. Do you really have to here?

Comment: thanx paul, i got u...

Answer (score 0):

You can 'close' your handlers for non-admin users in app.yaml

```
- url: .*
  script: main.application
  login: admin
```

Then, just add your three users as application owner/developer/viewer in Admin Console / Permissions. This users need to have registered google account to apply.