# get current user, python GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, authentication

I'm just trying to learn GAE, and I learn best by doing, so I wanted to create a website where you can log in. My problem is that after a person has logged in, my app forgets  the user. So far I have a main page, discussion page , registration page, and a log in page. I have a handler for each of these pages. At the log in page you can log in, and my app will check if the info is correct. And the current user is known for this handler, but if I change page, this gets wiped out. It would be great if you could help me out.

I know I can use the gmail thing that gae provides and use users.get_current_user(), but like I said, I do this to learn, so I wanted to make my own registration/login form. So in few words: What can I use/do beside users.get_current_user() to get current user that logged in using my log in form.

Thanks!

Newbeginner

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom authentication in google app engine (python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020736/custom-authentication-in-google-app-engine-python)

Comment: look at sessions? https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/sessions.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use the sessions library from webapp2. Sessions store info about the user for a certain duration set by you. You could store your sessions in the browser cookies, Memcache or Datastore. The session documentation can be found [here](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/sessions.html). Furthermore, [this](http://blog.abahgat.com/2013/01/07/user-authentication-with-webapp2-on-google-app-engine/) is a great walk-through post on how to do exactly what you’re asking about.

If you still face any problems or have any further questions let me know since I’ve done it before and believe can be of help to you.