# app.yaml "login: required" is not working

Tags: python, google-app-engine

**update**

Is this html code inside the template read.html the problem? Does this hyperlink circumvent the app.yaml's `login: required`?

```
(<a href ="/edit/{{ blog_id }}/{{ r.key().id() }}">edit </a>)
```

**update**

My app.yaml contains several `login: required` directives, but they do not seem to stop access while I am developing locally on GAE.

```
application: myapp 
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
- url: /.*
  script: main.app

- url: /create.*
  script: main.app
  login: required

- url: /createblog.*
  script: main.app
  login: required

- url: /editblog.*
  script: main.app
  login: required
```

My app's view.py begins as follows. Notice that toward the bottom, the template `edit.html` is triggered. But I want only logged in users to access that template. I don't even care if the user who is not logged is offered an opportunity to login.

```
import os
import jinja2
import webapp2

from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.api import users

TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(TEMPLATE_DIR ),
    extensions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape'],
    autoescape=True)

class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    @webapp2.cached_property
    def jinja2(self):
        return jinja2.get_jinja2(app=self.app)

    def render_template(
        self,
        filename,
        template_values,
        **template_args
        ):
    template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template(filename)
        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))


class EditReminder(BaseHandler):

    def get(self, blog_id, reminder_id):
        iden = int(reminder_id)
        reminder = db.get(db.Key.from_path('Blogs',blog_id,'Reminders', iden))
    self.render_template('edit.html', {'reminder': reminder, 'blog_id': blog_id})
```

[The answer here is informative, but ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29304395/)

a) My understanding is that the answer is referring to "static" files, which I assume are not like my templates in the sense that the templates are fed jinja inputs, and

b) Even if my templates are "static" files, I have not figured out how to implement the answer's recommendation.

So, how can these `login: required`s be made to work?

Comment: How have you decided it isn't working? If you have already logged-in on localhost, then the cookie will still be there. Visit /_ah/login and force a log-out, and see what happens.

Comment: When I visit ` /_ah/login` I see a dialog that says "not logged in" and invites me to either login or logout. I don't know how to check other cookies. I am using localhost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place your catch-all route

```
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```

at the bottom.

Comment: I had just returned after discovering this myself, when I saw your answer.